# running keytool command programmatically

Tags: java, keytool

I would like to run the following keytool command in java code:

```
keytool -v \
        -genkeypair \
        -dname "$SERVER_DN" \
        -keystore "$SERVER_DIR"/keystore.jks \
        -storepass "$SERVER_PW" \
        -keypass "$SERVER_PW" \
        -keyalg "EC" \
        -alias server \
        -validity 1825 \
        -deststoretype pkcs12 \
        -ext KU=digitalSignature,dataEncipherment,keyEncipherment,keyAgreement \
        -ext EKU=serverAuth \
        -ext SAN="$SERVER_SAN"
```

and would like to know the best way to do it programmatically. Is it possible at all?

Comment: You can create process by ProcessBuilder and you can run command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String command = "keytool -v \
    -genkeypair \
    -dname "$SERVER_DN" \
    -keystore "$SERVER_DIR"/keystore.jks \
    -storepass "$SERVER_PW" \
    -keypass "$SERVER_PW" \
    -keyalg "EC" \
    -alias server \
    -validity 1825 \
    -deststoretype pkcs12 \
    -ext KU=digitalSignature,dataEncipherment,keyEncipherment,keyAgreement \
    -ext EKU=serverAuth \
    -ext SAN="$SERVER_SAN""

 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe");
 Process process = pb.start();
 PrintWriter commandWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(process.getOutputStream())));
 commandWriter.println(command);
 commandWriter.flush();
```

Also you can read errorStream or inputStream from process.getErrorStream() and process.getInputStream.

Comment: what about environment parameters?

Comment: You can simply pass to command. Actually I didn't write it because it is easy to build command.

Comment: You can simply get from System class

Comment: System.getenv() or System.getProperty can work for you